# Prevent positioning of figures before mentioned in the text

Tags: floats, positioning

I'm currently working on my master thesis and my specification states that images are included at the top, bottom or their own page only after mentioned in the text. So I tried to use [tbp] for placement modifiers of my figures, but it happens that images are placed at the top of the current page, which is obviously before any text that mentions the image.

I want to position the images at the bottom of the current page, the top of the next page or their own page if everything else fails. I've looked at this question [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat) which doesn't really say how to change the default behavior and I've looked at the afterpage package, but it looks that it won't regard the bottom of the current page as a possibility.

So that in the following example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, parskip=full, bibtotoc, twoside, BCOR=5mm, draft=true]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\section{Example Section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua (See \ref{image}). At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 

\begin{figure}[tbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.66\textwidth]{example.png}
\caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.}
\label{image}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The image would not be included before the new section but rather at the bottom of the page, or the top of the next page (if there would be more text) or it's own page.

Answer (score 3):

add

```
\usepackage{flafter}
```

which is part of the base latex distribution and changes the definition of `t` not to allow `t` on the page on which the `figure` appears in the source, so that floats never go backwards.

Comment: I learn something new every day.  This sounds like a useful package when dealing with persnickety editors.